# Using a string as GPS coordinates

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3, gps

I am using javascript and I have GPS coordinates in the form of a string and I am trying to put those into the `google.maps.LatLng(59.327383, 18.06747)` format but am having trouble deciding how to do it.  I have a variable:

```
GPSlocation = "(37.700421688980136, -81.84535319999998)"
```

and I need it to go into that google.maps.LatLng(num, num) format.  How can I put this string in there?

Thanks!

Comment: I always laugh at the number of decimal places we get on lat/lon co-ords. Six DP is enough to pinpoint you to ten centimetres. I'm always amused when we get people insisting on eight or ten-digit co-ords. Your have even more than that, but that's more down to floating point inaccuracies than any kind of precision.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use standard string operations to extract the values:

```
var GPSlocation = "(37.700421688980136, -81.84535319999998)";
var LatLng = GPSlocation.replace("(", "").replace(")", "").split(", ")
var Lat = parseFloat(LatLng[0]);
var Lng = parseFloat(LatLng[1]);

google.maps.LatLng(Lat, Lng)
```

Comment: ah great, I knew how to do that in Python but wasn't thinking that I could do it in JS too though obviously I can.  thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can create an Array from it (using `JSON.parse`), and then use `apply` to 'feed' the coordinates to the method:

```
GPSlocation = JSON.parse( "(37.700421688980136, -81.84535319999998)" 
                          .replace(/^\(/,'[')
                          .replace(/\)$/,']')
                        );
google.maps.LatLng.apply(null,GPSlocation);
```

Alternatively you can replace the brackets and use `split` to create an Array, and call the method `LatLng` the regular way. This method requires an extra conversion to `Number` of the Array values.

```
GPSlocation = "(37.700421688980136, -81.84535319999998)"
               .replace(/^\(|\)$/,'')
               .split(',');
google.maps.LatLng(+GPSlocation[0],+GPSlocation[1]);
```

To retrieve an Array of coordinates from the string, you could also use:

```
GPSlocation = ''.slice.call('(37.700421688980136, -81.84535319999998)',
                             1,this.length-1)
                       .split(',')
                       .map(function(a){return +a;});
google.maps.LatLng(GPSlocation[0],GPSlocation[1]);
```